# missing the public's attention / out of the public's attention

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

How Do the following sentences differ in meaning?

> The billionaire lives his life **missing the public's attention**.
>
> The billionaire lives his life **out of the public's attention**.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence suggests that the billionaire is not getting any public attention, but wants (misses) it.

The second sentence suggests that the billionaire is not getting any public attention, by keeping a low profile.

Comment: Does "miss" necessarily mean lacking something desirable in this case?

I saw the following:

If we leave now we should miss the traffic.

Comment: If something is undesirable I would say "I **don't** miss it." Your example is a different use of the word "miss".

Comment: Couldn't "miss" mean "avoid" in "miss the public's attention" like "miss the traffic jam"?

Comment: I guess so, I was assuming the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miss) meaning ***4** to discover or feel the absence of*. If the two sentences are *intended* to mean the same thing, then the second one is better because it is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, *miss* has two different definitions that are almost opposites:

Two of the definitions of **miss** from [Lexico / Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/miss):

> 2. Fail to notice, hear, or understand.
> 3. Notice the loss or absence of.

In your first sentence, it is definition (3) which is the one that I would strongly think you were trying to use. It's hard for me to even think of it having the other meaning, unless I change the example to traffic like you did. I don't know exactly why that is. It does not feel ambiguous at all to me.  Maybe it's because a lonely person missing other people is much more common than someone being glad they aren't seeing people.

Comment: That was the way I read the first sentence too, without noticing any ambiguity. But perhaps non-native speakers don't have the same take on it.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I'm pretty curious why it doesn't feel more ambiguous. Perhaps also something to do with the continuous aspect of it. We wouldn't say, "I've lived my life missing traffic jams."

Comment: It would be more like "I spend my life dodging traffic jams."